# How to read in a file with a mixture of different delimiters using Python csv module?

Tags: python, csv

Input:

```
A    B    C
D    E    F
```

This file is NOT exclusively tab-delimited, some entries are space-delimited to look like they were tab-delimited (which is annoying).  I tried reading in the file with the `csv` module using the canonical tab delimited option hoping it wouldn't mind a few spaces (needless to say, my output came out botched with this code):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    input = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in input:
        print row
```

I then tried replacing the second line with `csv.reader('\t'.join(f.split()))` to try to take advantage of [Remove whitespace in Python using string.whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898656/remove-whitespace-in-python-using-string-whitespace/1898835#1898835) but my error was: `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'`.

I also tried examining [Can I import a CSV file and automatically infer the delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312104/python-import-csv-file-delimiter-or) but here the OP imported either semicolon-delimited or comma-delimited files, but not a file which was a random mixture of both kinds of delimiters.

Was wondering if the `csv` module can handle reading in files with a mix of various delimiters or whether I should try a different approach (e.g., not use the `csv` module)?

I am hoping that there exists a way to read in a file with a mixture of delimiters and automatically turn this file into a tab-delimited file.

Comment: Are your space delimited lines always delimited with the same number of spaces?

Comment: I would say it's probably best to normalize your file and then process it, than handling edge cases all day.

Comment: I agree, but how would I normalize/process it if the file is hundreds of lines long?  Perhaps there is a better alternative to the `csv` module?

Comment: Any fields that have quotes around them: `"A Dont break B"`?

Comment: @dawg: No quotes in the file fields.

Comment: Does every single tab or space denote a new field, or are there some fields with spaces within the field itself?

Comment: Every single tab or space denotes a new field (thankfully).

Comment: ...and that got the answers coming! :)

Comment: @Gerrat: Could you imagine the nightmare of dealing with fields that had spaces within the field? :)  Would that even be possible (don't think `split()` would get the job done)?

Comment: Yes I can - which is why I asked.  The answer to your question was either going to be trivial (which it was), or really ugly and error-prone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use .split():

```
csv='''\
A\tB\tC
D    E    F
'''

data=[]
for line in csv.splitlines():
    data.append(line.split())

print data 
# [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
>>> [line.split() for line in csv.splitlines()]  
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

For a file, something like:

```
with open(fn, 'r') as fin:
    data=[line.split() for line in fin]
```

It works because [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will split on all whitespace between data elements even if more than 1 whitespace character or if mixed:

```
>>> '1\t\t\t2     3\t  \t  \t4'.split()
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: +1 and accepted answer for showing how to accomplish with `.split()` what you wish `csv` module could easily do.

Comment: This approach will fail if the values have whitespace in them (e.g. strings set off with quote characters).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just roll your own splitter rather than the CSV module?

```
delimeters = [',', ' ', '\t']

unique = '[**This is a unique delimeter**]'

with open(fileName) as f:
    for l in f: 
        for d in delimeters: l = unique.join(l.split(d))
        row = l.split(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

.split() is an easy and nice solution for the situation that "consecutive, arbitrarily-mixed tabs and blanks as one delimiter"; However, this does not work while value with blank (enclosed by quote mark) appears.

First, we may replace each tab in the text file with one blank `' '`; This can simplify the situation to "consecutive, arbitrary-number of blanks as one delimiter".
There is a good example for replacing a pattern over a file:
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch04s04.html
**Note 1:** DO NOT replace with `''` (empty string), due to there may be a delimiter includes ONLY tabs.
**Note 2:** This approach DOES NOT work while you have tab character (*/t*) inside a value that enclosed by quote mark.

Then we can use Python's csv module, with delimiter as `' '` (one blank), and use `skipinitialspace=True` to ignore consecutive blanks.