# two quote character types in Python's csv module

Tags: python, csv

I am parsing a poorly written `csv` file with Python and am wondering, is there a way to have more than one quote character in Python's `csv.reader`?

For example, my file looks like this:

```
somedata, "some other data which is a string", [1,2,3,4]
moredata, "more data which may have commas ,", [12]
```

What I want is to do something like this:

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
r = csv.reader(quotechar='"', delimiter=',', bracketchar='[]')
    for row in r:
         print row[0]
```

Which would result in something like

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['12']
```

or at the very least something similar. I can, of course, do this by simply reading the file, but I feel like the `csv` module might enable a more elegant solution...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312104/python-import-csv-file-delimiter-or

Comment: No, the CSV module doesn't support nested sequences; that is not part of the defacto CSV format standard.