# python 3.4 import csv delimiter

Tags: python, csv, import, python-3.4, delimiter

Using Python 3.4 and Im trying to import csv files with some containing commas, others containing semicolons, and other containing tabs as delimiters.

Is it possible to let python detect which proper delimiter to use?
i have read the post on [python: import csv file (delimiter “;” or “,”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312104/python-import-csv-file-delimiter-or?newreg=c9b229f6445344fd97efd74397a8ef8d) but cannot get the appropriate result.

My code thus far:

```
import csv

class Data(object):
def __init__(self, csv_file):
    self.raw_data = []
    self.read(csv_file)

def read(self, csv_file):
        with open(csv_file, newline='') as csvfile:
            dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(), delimiters=',;')
            csvfile.seek(0)
            f = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
            for row in f:
               self.raw_data.append(row)
            print(self.raw_data)

mycsv = Data('comma_separate.csv')
```

comma_separate.csv contains:

```
afsfaf@faf.com, $161,321, True, 1
asafasf@fafa.net, $95.00, False, 3
adaafa3@aca.com, $952025, False, 3
```

Right now my output is:

```
['afsfaf@faf.com, $161,321, True, 1'], ['asafasf@fafa.net, $95.00, False, 3'], ['adaafa3@aca.com, $952025, False, 3']
```

My desired output is:

```
['afsfaf@faf.com', '$161,321', 'True', '1'], ['asafasf@fafa.net', '$95.00', 'False', '3'], ['adaafa3@aca.com', '$952025', 'False', '3']
```

Comment: This maybe help you. [read-data-from-csv-file-and-transform-to-correct-data-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665628/read-data-from-csv-file-and-transform-to-correct-data-type)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the first line of your csv-file that you are using to determine the delimiter. The program works as expected, if you change the line to:

```
afsfaf@faf.com, $161.321, True, 1
```

I guess the reason for that is that he wants to have the same number of attributes per line in your csv-file.

Answer (score 0):

use sniff without passing possible delimiters works for me

```
import csv

class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, csv_file):
        self.raw_data = []
        self.read(csv_file)

    def read(self, csv_file):
            with open(csv_file, newline='') as csvfile:
                dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read())
                csvfile.seek(0)
                f = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
                for row in f:
                   self.raw_data.append(row)

                print(csvfile.name)
                print(self.raw_data)


for f in ['tab_separate.tsv','comma_separate.csv','comma_separate2.csv']:
    mycsv = Data(f)
```

output

```
tab_separate.tsv
[['afsfaf@faf.com', '$161,321', 'True', '1'], ['asafasf@fafa.net', '$95.00', 'False', '3'], ['adaafa3@aca.com', '$952025', 'False', '3']]
comma_separate.csv
[['afsfaf@faf.com,', '$161,321,', 'True,', '1'], ['asafasf@fafa.net,', '$95.00,', 'False,', '3'], ['adaafa3@aca.com,', '$952025,', 'False,', '3']]
comma_separate2.csv
[['afsfaf@faf.com', '$161,321', 'True', '1'], ['asafasf@fafa.ne', '$95.00', 'False', '3'], ['adaafa3@aca.com', '$952025', 'False', '3']]
```

comma input

```
afsfaf@faf.com, $161,321, True, 1
asafasf@fafa.net, $95.00, False, 3
adaafa3@aca.com, $952025, False, 3
```

tab input

```
afsfaf@faf.com  $161,321    True    1
asafasf@fafa.net    $95.00  False   3
adaafa3@aca.com $952025 False   3
```

semi colon input

```
afsfaf@faf.com;$161,321;True;1
asafasf@fafa.ne;$95.00;False;3
adaafa3@aca.com;$952025;False;3
```

Comment: That's odd. I even copied you code as well as the comma_separate.csv file and it still gives me this output:

comma_separate.csv
    [['afsfaf@faf.com, $161,321, True, 1'], ['asafasf@fafa.net, $95.00, False, 3'], ['adaafa3@aca.com, $952025, False, 3']]'

Are you using Python 3.4 as well?

Comment: Yes 3.4. looking at it again, I think mine is splitting on the space in the comma separated file rather than the comma. ie it thinks its a space delimited file. Could you upload the csv input somewhere?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxeHWbvOxiOTYU15N200S3R4cVk/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxeHWbvOxiOTb1hSYTVaTl9oZUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have resolved issue. Was a format error with MS Excel. Used Libreoffice to make csv files and they now work. Go figure..