# How to determine the delimiter in CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I have a scenario at which i have to parse CSV files from different sources, the parsing code is very simple and straightforward.

```
        String csvFile = "/Users/csv/country.csv";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // use comma as separator
                String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                System.out.println("Country [code= " + country[4] + " , name=" + country[5] + "]");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

my problem come from the CSV delimiter character, i have many different formats, some time it is a `,` sometimes it is a `;`

is there is any way to determine the delimiter character before parsing the file

Comment: *i have many different formats*. What would be allowed delimiter set? Comma, colon, semicolon...?

Comment: @zlakad, yes Comma, colon, semicolon

Comment: do you need to handle numbers with commas for decimal seperators? (Often why they used something other than a comma for the field sep..)

Comment: So, sometimes your file should be split by `,`, sometimes by `(`? **AND** every file should allow occurrence of not-delimiter chars? I don't know if something like this can be coded without linking **file-separator**.

Comment: @agentp, no it will be decimal point

Comment: This question depends too much on the files you will have and their format.  You need to post more information for this to be a meaningful question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) supports automatic detection of the delimiter (also line endings and quotes). Just use it instead of fighting with your code:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.detectFormatAutomatically();

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> rows = parser.parseAll(new File("/path/to/your.csv"));

// if you want to see what it detected
CsvFormat format = parser.getDetectedFormat();
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library and I made sure all sorts of corner cases are covered. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! I'll definitely check out your library. Thank you!

Comment: Don't we have this feature of detect format in apache common csv library?

Comment: @Pavan As far as I can tell, Commons CSV does not have that. Commons CSV does have [header autodetection](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Header_auto_detection), but I do not see delimiter or format detection in the docs.

Comment: @vlz univocity has this feature and features looks much good. have a look at that also.

Comment: This works well if you supplied the set of delimited characters. However if you set auto-detection and not supplied set of allowed delimiters , i can see bugs. example: simple csv like this ( tab separated) it failed to identify the tab as delimiter example O__\tB__

Comment: @csf this was designed to detect delimiters from a larger input with multiple rows. A single line is not enough to detect anything reliably.

Comment: @JeronimoBackes fair enough, i hope project is not dead as i like to use it , however last update for year ago and may PR out standing.  Anyways Really good job , keep it up!

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, but only if the delimiter characters are not allowed to exist as regular text

The most simple answer is to have a list with all the available delimiter characters and try to identify which character is being used. Even though, you have to place some **limitations** on the files or the person/people that created them. Look a the following two scenarios:

**Case 1 - Contents of file.csv**

```
test,test2,test3
```

**Case 2 - Contents of file.csv**

```
test1|test2,3|test4
```

If you have prior knowledge of the delimiter characters, then you would split the first string using `,` and the second one using `|`, getting the same result. But, if you try to identify the delimiter by parsing the file, **both strings** can be split using the `,` character, and you would end up with this:

**Case 1 - Result of split using `,`**

```
test1
test2
test3
```

**Case 2 - Result of split using `,`**

```
test1|test2
3|test4
```

By lacking the prior knowledge of which delimiter character is being used, you cannot create a "magical" algorithm that will parse every combination of text; even regular expressions or counting the number of appearance of a character will not save you.

**Worst case**

```
test1,2|test3,4|test5
```

By looking the text, one can tokenize it by using `|` as the delimiter. But the frequency of appearance of both `,` and `|` are the same. So, from an algorithm's perspective, both results are accurate:

**Correct result**

```
test1,2
test3,4
test5
```

**Wrong result**

```
test1
2|test3
4|test5
```

If you pose a set of guidelines or you can somehow control the generation of the CSV files, then you could just try to find the delimiter used with `String.contains()` method, employing the aforementioned list of characters. For example:

```
public class MyClass {

    private List<String> delimiterList = new ArrayList<>(){{
        add(",");
        add(";");
        add("\t");
        // etc...
    }};

    private static String determineDelimiter(String text) {
        for (String delimiter : delimiterList) {
            if(text.contains(delimiter)) {
                return delimiter;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "/Users/csv/country.csv";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        String delimiter = "";
        boolean firstLine = true;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile)))  {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(firstLine) {
                    delimiter = determineDelimiter(line);
                    if(delimiter.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        System.out.println("Unsupported delimiter found: " + delimiter);
                        return;
                    }
                    firstLine = false;
                }
                // use comma as separator
                String[] country = line.split(delimiter);
                System.out.println("Country [code= " + country[4] + " , name=" + country[5] + "]");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

For a more optimized way, in `determineDelimiter()` method instead of the `for-each` loop, you can employ regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If the delimiter can appear in a data column, then you are asking for the impossible. For example, consider this first line of a CSV file:

```
one,two:three
```

This could be either a comma-separated or a colon-separated file. You can't tell which type it is.

If you can guarantee that the first line has all its columns surrounded by quotes, for example if it's always this format:

```
"one","two","three"
```

then you may be able to use this logic (although it's not 100% bullet-proof):

```
if (line.contains("\",\""))
    delimiter = ',';
else if (line.contains("\";\""))
    delimiter = ';';
```

If you can't guarantee a restricted format like that, then it would be better to pass the delimiter character as a parameter.

Then you can read the file using a widely-known open-source CSV parser such as [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html).

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Lefteris008 that it is not possible to have the function that correctly determine all the cases, we can have a function that is both efficient and give mostly correct result in practice.

```
def head(filename: str, n: int):
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            head_lines = [next(f).rstrip() for x in range(n)]
    except StopIteration:
        with open(filename) as f:
            head_lines = f.read().splitlines()
    return head_lines


def detect_delimiter(filename: str, n=2):
    sample_lines = head(filename, n)
    common_delimiters= [',',';','\t',' ','|',':']
    for d in common_delimiters:
        ref = sample_lines[0].count(d)
        if ref > 0:
            if all([ ref == sample_lines[i].count(d) for i in range(1,n)]):
                return d
    return ','
```

My efficient implementation is based on

1. Prior knowledge such as list of common delimiter you often work with ',;\t |:' , or even the likely hood of the delimiter to be used so that I often put the regular ',' on the top of the list
2. The frequency of the delimiter appear in each line of the text file are equal. This is to resolve the problem that if we read a single line and see the frequency to be equal (false detection as Lefteris008) or even the right delimiter to appear less frequent as the wrong one in the first line
3. The efficient implementation of a head function that  [read only first n lines from the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767513/how-to-read-first-n-lines-of-a-file/68309127#68309127)

4. As you increase the number of test sample n, the likely hood that you get a false answer reduce drastically. I often found n=2 to be adequate

Answer (score -1):

That depends....

If your datasets are always the same length and/or the separator NEVER occurs in your datacolumns, you could just read the first line of the file, look at it for the longed for separator, set it and then read the rest of the file using that separator.

Something like

```
String csvFile = "/Users/csv/country.csv";
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // use comma as separator
        if (line.contains(",")) {
            cvsSplitBy = ",";
        } else if (line.contains(";")) {
           cvsSplitBy = ";";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong separator!");
        }
        String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        System.out.println("Country [code= " + country[4] + " , name=" + country[5] + "]");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Greetz Kai

Comment: i cannot guarantee "NEVER occurs"  part

Comment: @MeladEzzat if you cannot guarantee that the data columns NEVER contain the delimiter, then you shouldn't be using `String.split()`.

Comment: @MeladEzzat In that case - how would you determine how to split your data in any case?! ;-) I'd try to simplify/unify the formats to import - that would be the easiest way to go, as far as I see...

Comment: Does the downvoter care to let me know WHY he/she downvoted?!

Answer (score -1):

Add a condition like this,

```
String [] country;
if(line.contains(",")
    country = line.split(",");
else if(line.contains(";"))
    country=line.split(";");
```

Comment: what if the data contains one of the characters  , or ;

Comment: I think some more else if conditions will be added for those extra characters.